# Accordo del verbo nelle frasi passive

Tags: grammar, verbs, grammatical-number, agreement

Quale delle due seguenti frasi è corretta? "Ad ogni prodotto viene assegnato un codice e un'etichetta" oppure "Ad ogni prodotto vengono assegnate un codice e un'etichetta"?

Comment: Giusto. Chiedo scusa. La domando è se nella frase passiva in relazione a due complementi devo usare viene o vengono.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Che il verbo sia in diatesi attiva, passiva o riflessiva non è importante. Quello che conta è chi sia il soggetto.

Il soggetto della frase è *Un codice e un'etichetta*, che è composto da un sostantivo maschile singolare e un sostantivo femminile singolare. Citando l'Enciclopedia dell'Italiano Treccani, alla voce [accordo](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/accordo-prontuario_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/):

> più soggetti singolari collegati per asindeto (nello scritto, con virgola) o con una congiunzione copulativa (*e*) sono seguiti di norma da un verbo al plurale (*il pollice, l’indice, il medio, l’anulare e il mignolo sono le dita della mano*); se invece i soggetti sono percepiti come semanticamente unitari, o l’uno come riformulazione dell’altro, è possibile l’accordo al singolare: *la maestosità e regalità del suo portamento ricorda personaggi d’altri tempi*, con omissione dell’articolo, a sottolineare la solidarietà semantica del binomio;

In questo caso direi che "codice" ed "etichetta" non sono percepiti come un attributo unitario, ma distinti: il verbo va al plurale, *vengono*. Il testo continua, ricordando le norme per il participio

> con una sequenza di nomi di entrambi i generi il participio o l’aggettivo predicativo sono al maschile plurale (*il barista e la cassiera sono usciti / simpatici*);

Per cui la frase corretta è: **Ad ogni prodotto vengono assegnati un codice e un'etichetta**

Da notare che, al contrario di entrambe le proposte nella domanda, il participio passato deve essere messo al maschile plurale.

Comment: Grazie. È più appropriato l'uso del verbo venire o essere (e.g. Sono assegna)? Opporre sono equivalenti?

Comment: @drSlump In questo caso sono equivalenti (*vengono/sono assegnati*). In alcune frasi l'uso del verbo *essere* è sconsigliato (e.g. nella forma progressiva: *I ruderi stanno venendo abbattuti* e non **stanno essendo abbattuti*). Se ti rimangono dubbi sulla questione, chiedi pure un'altra domanda :)

Comment: @drSlump Puoi trovare ulteriori informazioni sull'uso di venire come ausiliare in [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8324/when-is-venire-used-as-an-auxiliary-verb/8325)